# Creating hierarchical data (tree) structures in Neo4j using "tree keys"

Tags: database, neo4j, tree

I have imported data from a **CSV** file and created a lot of Nodes, all of which are **related to other Nodes** within the same data set based on a "Tree Number" hierarchy system:

For example, the Node with *Tree Number* **A01.111** is a direct child of Node **A01**, and the Node with *Tree Number* **A01.111.230** is a direct child of Node **A01.111**.

**What I am trying to do** is create unique relationships between Nodes that are direct children of other Nodes. For example Node **A01.111.230** should *only* have one "IS_CHILD_OF" relationship, with Node **A01.111**.

**I have tried** several things, for example:

```
MATCH (n:Node), (n2:Node)
WHERE (n2.treeNumber STARTS WITH n.treeNumber)
AND (n <> n2)
AND NOT ((n2)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->())
CREATE UNIQUE (n2)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(n);
```

This example results in creating unique "IS_CHILD_OF" relationships but *not* with the direct parent of a Node. Rather, Node **A01.111.230** would be related to Node **A01**.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest another general solution, also avoiding a cartesian product as @InverseFalcon points out.

Let's indeed start by creating an index for faster lookup, and inserting some test data:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.treeNumber IS UNIQUE;
CREATE (n:Node {treeNumber: 'A01.111.230'})
CREATE (n:Node {treeNumber: 'A01.111'})
CREATE (n:Node {treeNumber: 'A01'})
```

Then we need to scan all nodes as potential parents, and look for children which start with the `treeNumber` of the parent (`STARTS WITH` can use the index) *and have no dots in the "remainder" of the `treeNumber`* (i.e. a direct child), instead of splitting, joining, etc.:

```
MATCH (p:Node), (c:Node)
WHERE c.treeNumber STARTS WITH p.treeNumber
  AND p <> c
  AND NOT substring(c.treeNumber, length(p.treeNumber) + 1) CONTAINS '.'
RETURN p, c
```

I replaced the creation of the relationship by a simple `RETURN` for profiling purposes, but you can simply replace it by `CREATE UNIQUE` or `MERGE`.

Actually, we can get rid of the `p <> c` predicate **and** the `+ 1` on the length by pre-computing the actual prefix which should match:

```
MATCH (p:Node)
WITH p, p.treeNumber + '.' AS parentNumber
MATCH (c:Node)
WHERE c.treeNumber STARTS WITH parentNumber
  AND NOT substring(c.treeNumber, length(parentNumber)) CONTAINS '.'
RETURN p, c
```

However, profiling that query shows that the index is **not used**, and there **is** a cartesian product (so we have a *O(n^2)* algorithm):

```
Compiler CYPHER 3.0

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

+--------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator           | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables            | Other                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults    |              2 |    2 |       0 | c, p                 | p, c                                                                                                                               |
| |                  +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter            |              2 |    2 |      26 | c, p, parentNumber   | NOT(Contains(SubstringFunction(c.treeNumber,length(parentNumber),None),{  AUTOSTRING1})) AND StartsWith(c.treeNumber,parentNumber) |
| |                  +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Apply             |              2 |    9 |       0 | p, parentNumber -- c |                                                                                                                                    |
| |\                 +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +NodeByLabelScan |              9 |    9 |      12 | c                    | :Node                                                                                                                              |
| |                  +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection        |              3 |    3 |       3 | parentNumber -- p    | p; Add(p.treeNumber,{  AUTOSTRING0})                                                                                               |
| |                  +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan   |              3 |    3 |       4 | p                    | :Node                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 45
```

But, if we simple add a hint like so

```
MATCH (p:Node)
WITH p, p.treeNumber + '.' AS parentNumber
MATCH (c:Node)
USING INDEX c:Node(treeNumber)
WHERE c.treeNumber STARTS WITH parentNumber
  AND NOT substring(c.treeNumber, length(parentNumber)) CONTAINS '.'
RETURN p, c
```

it does use the index and we have something like a *O(n*log(n))* algorithm (*log(n)* for the index lookup):

```
Compiler CYPHER 3.0

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

+-------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator                      | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables            | Other                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults               |              2 |    2 |       0 | c, p                 | p, c                                                                                     |
| |                             +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter                       |              2 |    2 |       6 | c, p, parentNumber   | NOT(Contains(SubstringFunction(c.treeNumber,length(parentNumber),None),{  AUTOSTRING1})) |
| |                             +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Apply                        |              2 |    3 |       0 | p, parentNumber -- c |                                                                                          |
| |\                            +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +NodeUniqueIndexSeekByRange |              9 |    3 |       6 | c                    | :Node(treeNumber STARTS WITH parentNumber)                                               |
| |                             +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection                   |              3 |    3 |       3 | parentNumber -- p    | p; Add(p.treeNumber,{  AUTOSTRING0})                                                     |
| |                             +----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan              |              3 |    3 |       4 | p                    | :Node                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 19
```

Note that I did cheat a bit when introducing the `WITH` step creating the prefix earlier, as I noticed it improved the execution plan and DB accesses over

```
MATCH (p:Node), (c:Node)
USING INDEX c:Node(treeNumber)
WHERE c.treeNumber STARTS WITH p.treeNumber
  AND p <> c
  AND NOT substring(c.treeNumber, length(p.treeNumber) + 1) CONTAINS '.'
RETURN p, c
```

which has the following execution plan:

```
Compiler CYPHER 3.0

Planner RULE

Runtime INTERPRETED

+--------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator     | Rows | DB Hits | Variables | Other                                                                                                                      |
+--------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter      |    2 |       9 | c, p      | NOT(p == c) AND NOT(Contains(SubstringFunction(c.treeNumber,Add(length(p.treeNumber),{  AUTOINT0}),None),{  AUTOSTRING1})) |
| |            +------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +SchemaIndex |    6 |      12 | c -- p    | PrefixSeekRangeExpression(p.treeNumber); :Node(treeNumber)                                                                 |
| |            +------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabel |    3 |       4 | p         | :Node                                                                                                                      |
+--------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 25
```

---

Finally, for the record, the execution plan of the original query I wrote (i.e. without the hint) was:

```
Compiler CYPHER 3.0

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

+--------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator           | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables | Other                                                                                                                                                                |
+--------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults    |              2 |    2 |       0 | c, p      | p, c                                                                                                                                                                 |
| |                  +----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter            |              2 |    2 |      21 | c, p      | NOT(p == c) AND StartsWith(c.treeNumber,p.treeNumber) AND NOT(Contains(SubstringFunction(c.treeNumber,Add(length(p.treeNumber),{  AUTOINT0}),None),{  AUTOSTRING1})) |
| |                  +----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +CartesianProduct  |              9 |    9 |       0 | p -- c    |                                                                                                                                                                      |
| |\                 +----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| | +NodeByLabelScan |              3 |    9 |      12 | c         | :Node                                                                                                                                                                |
| |                  +----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan   |              3 |    3 |       4 | p         | :Node                                                                                                                                                                |
+--------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 37
```

It's not the worse one: the one without the hint but with the pre-computed prefix is! This is why you should always measure.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can improve on the query a bit. First, ensure you have either a unique constraint or an index on :Node.treeNumber, as you'll need that to improve your parent node lookups in this query.

Next, let's match on child nodes, excluding root nodes (assuming no .'s in the root's treeNumber) and nodes that have already been processed and have a relationship already.

Then we'll find each node's parent by the treeNumber using our index, and create the relationship. This assumes that a child treeNumber always has 4 more characters, including the dot.

```
MATCH (child:Node)
WHERE child.treeNumber CONTAINS '.'
AND NOT EXISTS( (child)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->() )
WITH child, SUBSTRING(child.treeNumber, 0, SIZE(child.treeNumber)-4) as parentNumber
MATCH (parent:Node)
WHERE parent.treeNumber = parentNumber
CREATE UNIQUE (child)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(parent)
```

I think this query avoids a cartesian product as you may get from other answers, and should be around O(n) (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

EDIT

In the event that each subset of numbers in treeNumbers is NOT constrained to 3 (as in your description, actually, with 'A01.111.23'), then you need a different means of deriving the parentNumber. Neo4j is a little weak here, as it lacks both an indexOf() function as well as a join() function to reverse a split(). You may need the [APOC Procedures library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_phonetic_comparisons) installed to allow access to a join() function.

The query to handle cases with variable counts of digits in the numeric subsets of treeNumber becomes this:

```
MATCH (child:Node)
WHERE child.treeNumber CONTAINS '.'
AND NOT EXISTS( (child)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->() )
WITH child, SPLIT(child.treeNumber, '.') as splitNumber
CALL apoc.text.join(splitNumber[0..-1], '.') YIELD value AS parentNumber
WITH child, parentNumber
MATCH (parent:Node)
WHERE parent.treeNumber = parentNumber
CREATE UNIQUE (child)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured out a solution! (If someone has a more elegant one please do post)

I just realized that the "Tree Number" coding system always uses 3-digit numbers between the dots, i.e. **A01.111.230** or **C02.100**, therefore if a Node is the direct child of another Node, it's "Tree Number" should *not only* start with the Tree Number of the parent Node, it should also be 4 characters longer (one character for the dot '.' and 3 characters for the numeric value).

**Therefore my solution that seems to do the job is:**

```
MATCH (n:Node), (n2:Node)
WHERE (n2.treeNumber STARTS WITH n.treeNumber)
AND (length(n2.treeNumber) = (length(n.treeNumber) + 4)) 
CREATE UNIQUE (n2)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(n);
```

Comment: This may perform a cartesian product, making this an n^2 operation. Also, your description has an example 'A01.111.23', which breaks your assumption that there are 3 digits in each numerical subset of treeNumbers. Not a bad stab at the problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement `STARTS WITH`  won't work, since *A01.111.23* does indeed start with *A01* in addition to starting with *A01.111*.

The `treeNumber` is made up of several parts with '.' as the separator. Let's not make any assumptions about the maximum/minimum possible character lengths of the individual parts. What we need is to compare all but the last part of each node's `treeNumber` with that of the potential child node being tested. You can achieve this using Cypher's `split()` function as follows:

```
MATCH (n1:Node), (n2:Node)
WHERE split(n2.treeNumber,'.')[0..-1] = split(n1.treeNumber,'.')
CREATE UNIQUE (n2)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(n1);
```

The `split()` function splits a string, at each occurrence of a given separator, into a list of strings (parts). In this context the separator is '.' to split any `treeNumber`. We can select a subset of a list in cypher using the syntax `list[{startIndex}..{endIndex}]`. Negative indices for reverse lookup are permitted, such ass the one used in the above query.

This solution should generalize to all possible `treeNumber` values, in the format at hand, irrespective of number of parts and individual part lengths.

Comment: While I agree that a generalized solution is preferable, I think your query may not take advantage of an index or constraint on treeNumber, and also may be performing a cartesian product. Not a problem with a small data set, but could be an issue with a larger set, or if it's going to be run more than once.